# MainActivity is not showing log statements

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Hi I am new to android development and the problem is Whenever I am using MainActivity in logcat as a filter it is not showing me Log statements for this  `Log.i(TAG, "TAG on Fb")`(my tag is also MainActivity) and `Log.i(TAG, "onitemclick $position")` for this it is shown by its function that is `onItemClick` but the same happen with this statement whenever I am trying to filter it on the basis of MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        userMaps = generateSampleData() as MutableList<user>
        //set layout manager on the screen => RV
        rvmaps.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        //set adapter on RV
         mapAdapter = mapadapter(this, userMaps, object: mapadapter.OnClickListener{
            override fun onitemclick(position: Int) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onitemclick $position")
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, googlemaps::class.java)
                // here we will use putextra which help us to put extra data to another activity through data
                intent.putExtra(user_data_map, userMaps[position])
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
        rvmaps.adapter = mapAdapter
        fabcreatemap.setOnClickListener{
            Log.i(TAG, "TAG on Fb")
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, createmap::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(user_map_title, "new map name")
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestcode)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        if(requestcode == requestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            val usermap = data?.getSerializableExtra(user_data_map) as user
          //  userMaps.add(usermap)
         //   mapAdapter.notifyItemChanged(userMaps.size-1)
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

}
```

Comment: hello and welcome to Android Development! :D.
does the rest of the code of the fabCreateMap.setOnClickListner is working? or it is only the log.i that is not working?

Comment: What exactly in TAG supposed to be initialized to?